# ERROR AL QUERER ENVIAR POST a PHP por medio de AJAX PARA ACTUALIZAR UN REGISTRO

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, script, modal

ESTOY INTENTANDO DESDE TEMPRANO Y NO PUEDO SOLUCIONARLO, CUANDO USO MODAL YA NO ME ENVIA LOS DATOS A $POST, YA LO INTENTÉ IMPLEMENTAR SIN MODAL Y SI ENVÍA PERO LO NECESITO ASI PARA MI PROYECTO :( SI ALGUIEN ME PUDIESE AYUDAR, GRACIAS!

Me aparece un error al querer enviar datos por ajax:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "idProductoU" in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pedidosd\procesos\productos\actualizaProductosConLote1.php on line 8
Warning: Undefined array key "categoriaSelectUU" in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pedidosd\procesos\productos\actualizaProductosConLote1.php on line 9
Warning: Undefined array key "productoUU" in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pedidosd\procesos\productos\actualizaProductosConLote1.php on line 10
Warning: Undefined array key "descripcionUU" in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pedidosd\procesos\productos\actualizaProductosConLote1.php on line 11
Warning: Undefined array key "uniMedidaUU" in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pedidosd\procesos\productos\actualizaProductosConLote1.php on line 12 `Warning: Undefined array key "cantidadUU" in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pedidosd\procesos\productos\actualizaProductosConLote1.php on line 13`
```

ESTE ES EL SCRIPT DE AJAX PARA ENVIAR LOS DATOS DEL FORMULARIO Y ACTUALICE MI REGISTRO:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btnAgregarLote').click(function(){
                datos=$('#frmProductosLote').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:datos,
                    url:"../procesos/productos/actualizaProductosConLote1.php",
                    success:function(r){
                        alert(r);
                        if(r==1){
                            $('#frmProductosLote')[0].reset();
                            alertify.success("Actualizado con exito");
                        }else{
                            alertify.error("Error al actualizar");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

LA CUAL RECIBO EN ESTE .PHP Y LLAMA AL METODO DE actualizarProducto.

```php
<?php 
require_once "../../clases/Conexion.php";
require_once "../../clases/Productos.php";

$obj= new productos();
$datos=array(

    $_POST['idProductoU'],
    $_POST['categoriaSelectUU'],
    $_POST['productoUU'],
    $_POST['descripcionUU'],
    $_POST['uniMedidaUU'],
    $_POST['cantidadUU']
);

 echo $obj->actualizaProducto1($datos);

?>
```

El script me funciona bien cuando esta sin modal, al momento de implementar el modal y actualizar me genera ese error mencionado arriba

MI MODAL:

```html
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="abremodalLote" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="frmProductosLote">Agregar Lote</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label>Producto</label>
                    <br>
                    <select class="form-control" style="width:100%" id="ProductoLote" name="ProductoLote">
                        <option value="A">Selecciona</option>
                            <?php //select todos los productos
                            $sql="SELECT id_producto,nombreProducto
                            from producto";
                            $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                            while($producto=mysqli_fetch_row($result)): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $producto[0] ?>"><?php echo $producto[1]; ?></option>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </select>
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input readonly type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="productoUU" id="productoUU">
                        <label>Categoria</label>
                        <select readonly class="form-control input-sm" id="categoriaSelectUU" name="categoriaSelectUU">
                            <option value="A">Selecciona Categoria</option>
                            <?php 
                            $sql="SELECT id_categoria,nombreCategoria
                            from categoria";
                            $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                            ?>
                            <?php while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $ver[0] ?>"><?php echo $ver[1]; ?></option>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </select>
                        <label>Unidad de Medida</label>
                        <input readonly type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="uniMedidaUU" id="uniMedidaUU">
                        
                        <label>Cantidad Actual</label>
                        <input readonly type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="cantidadActual" id="cantidadActual">

                        <label>Cantidad a Agregar</label>
                        <input  type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="cantidadUU" id="cantidadUU">

                        <label>Descripción</label>
                        <textarea readonly class="form-control" name="descripcionUU" id="descripcionUU" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">CERRAR</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAgregarLote">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! quien hace el submit? el modal? fijate que variables manda...

Comment: En general en el Internet, escribir TODO en mayúsculas se considera gritar. Sugiero amablemente que [edit] tu pregunta y cambies el texto en mayúsculas por texto normal. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los datos a enviar, estás tratando de serializar un elemento de tipo `<h5>`, que no es contenedor de los datos y que, en mi opinión, no tiene sentido *serializar*.

En el ejemplo de abajo he añadido un `<form>`, que es el que serializo. Luego dejo en consola el resultado de serializar este formulario y de serializar el `h5` original o el `div` contenedor, para que veas la diferencia.

Estos son los datos que envías en el post, y por eso del lado del servidor estás viendo el error de que no se encuentra el dato en el arreglo `$_POST`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnAgregarLote').click(function(){
    datos=$('#MiFormulario').serialize();
    console.log("datos de formulario: ", datos);
    
    datos2 = $('#frmProductosLote').serialize();
    console.log("datos de h5:", datos2)

    datos3 = $('#miDiv').serialize();
    console.log("datos de div:", datos3)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="abremodalLote" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="frmProductosLote">Agregar Lote</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="miDiv" class="modal-body">
        <form id="MiFormulario">
          <label>Producto</label>
          <br>
          <select class="form-control" style="width:100%" id="ProductoLote" name="ProductoLote">
            <option value="A">Selecciona</option>
            <option value="B">Producto B</option>
            <option value="B">Producto C</option>
          </select>
          <label>Nombre</label>
          <input readonly type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="productoUU" id="productoUU" value="producto de prueba">
          <label>Categoria</label>
          <select readonly class="form-control input-sm" id="categoriaSelectUU" name="categoriaSelectUU">
            <option value="A">Selecciona Categoria</option>
            <option value="B" selected>Alimentos</option>
            <option value="C">Bebidas</option>
          </select>
          <label>Unidad de Medida</label>
          <input readonly type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="uniMedidaUU" id="uniMedidaUU" value="Unidad">
          <label>Cantidad Actual</label>
          <input readonly type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="cantidadActual" id="cantidadActual" value="10">
          <label>Cantidad a Agregar</label>
          <input  type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="cantidadUU" id="cantidadUU" value="100">
          <label>Descripción</label>
          <textarea readonly class="form-control" name="descripcionUU" id="descripcionUU" rows="3">Esto es una prueba</textarea>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">CERRAR</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAgregarLote">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El ejemplo está en un *snippet* que puedes probar aquí mismo en el navegador haciendo clic en el botón *Ejecutar*.

Considero que ya con eso puedes hacer las adaptaciones en tu código.

---

**Edición**:

Justo ahora me he dado cuenta que en el código del POST también buscas campos que no has incliudo en el formulario. Creo que resulta obvio que solo encontrarás los campos que tú mismo has colocado allí. No he verificado todos los campos, pero veo que primero buscas el campo `idProductoU` que no existe en el formulario y por tanto no existe en el POST y luego el campo `categoriaSelectUU` que si que existe en el formulario.

Debes revisar esto detenidamente y asegurarte que has incluido todos los campos que esperas encontrar. Recuerda que puedes usar un campo oculto `<input type="hidden">` para poner un valor que luego te retorne y no esté a la vista del usuario.

Comment: Buenas noches, ya modifiqué el codigo y lo puse con el <form>pero me sigue apareciendo lo mismo "Warning: Undefined array key "idProductoU" in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pedidosd\procesos\productos\actualizaProductosConLote1.php on line 8
Warning: Undefined array key "categoriaSelectUU" in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pedidosd\procesos\productos\actualizaProductosConLote1.php on line 9"  y asi con todos los demás... Podría ser otra cosa más? Algo con el modal? @jachguate

Comment: ¿Te has asegurado que la variable, en este caso, si lleve los datos?. Pregunto porque me parece que no los lleva y es bastante común que se cuele algún error que provoque este comportamiento. Una técnica común es hacer una llamada a console.log para asegurarte que la variable va llena antes de hacer el POST. Si no va, pues ir identificando por qué no. Como he demostrado en mi código, si que es posible recoger la información.

Comment: `cantidadProducto
: 
"53"
descripcionProducto
: 
"PAPEL MULTIUSOS"
id_categoria
: 
"2"
id_producto
: 
"3"
nombreProducto
: 
"PAPEL TOALLA SCOTT"
uniMedidaProducto
: 
"UND"` Al seleccionar el producto, si lo captura, saque esa informacion desde la consola pero al querer pasar el POST aparece lo anteriormente comentado

Comment: Ahora estoy viendo que en el POST buscas el campo `idProductoU` que no incluyes en los campos del formulario. Creo que resulta obvio que vas a tener acceso a lo que tu mismo has puesto allí, y no a otras cosas. Si quieres tener de vuelta un campo llamado `idProductoU` colócalo en el formulario (puede estar oculto si no quieres que lo vea el usuario).

Comment: Si, ya lo agregué y lo tengo oculto, estuve ordenando el codigo hace rato y ya tengo todo como deberia para que funcione pero nada :( he buscado informacion pero se supone que debería funcionar

Comment: Edité mi respuesta por ese detalle. OJO, que al serializar el formulario el formato va con signos de igual (`=`), no con dos puntos (`:`) por lo que el texto que pegaste no puede ser el resultado de la serialización.

Comment: Uhmm, al momento de seleccionar el select2 e inspeccionar elemento, en "NETWORK" aparecen de la forma que le mandé, entonces estaría mal?

Comment: Ahora verificando en otro formulario e igual cargando la informacion con select2, me aparece de la misma forma y si captura los datos, pero al querer hacerlo en el modal de producto me esta sucediendo eso :(

Comment: Diría que el hecho que sea en modal no tiene nada que ver. ¿Ves alguna diferencia en los datos entre modal y no modal?

Comment: Lo pude solucionar, con modal (supongo) ajax estaba enviando los datos con signos de (=) y array creo q los estaba recibiendo en (:) y no podia( eso entiendo yo) tuve que sacar el valor de cada imput sin la serializacion del form, meterlos en el data con (:) y así, si hacia el POST. Mando la solución :) `$.ajax({
    type:"POST",     
    data:{idproductoA: idproductoU, categoriaA: categoriaUU, productoA: productoUU, descripcionA: descripcionUU, uniMedidaA: uniMedidaUU, cantidadA: cantidadUU},
    url:"URL.php",
    success:function(r){`  Si los enviaba con (=) en vez de (:), no jalaba.